# MySQL Command what does a point mean?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm a newbie in mysql and have to write a implemention for a custom mysql asp.net identity storage.

I follow this tutorial and the first steps are done.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider
Now i have the follow mysql command:

```
"Select Roles.Name from UserRoles, Roles where UserRoles.UserId = @userId and UserRoles.RoleId = Roles.Id"
```

My problem is now that i dont know how the table have to look for this request?

I would say:
Tablename : Roles
Select: Roles and Name? or is it a name?
same with UserRoles.UserID and UserRoles.RoleId
What does the point mean?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `Roles.Name` means the `Name` field of the `Roles` table.

Comment: You should research the `JOIN` clause in database commands. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp. Because you use 2 tables. `Roles` and `UserRoles` but there is no join between them.

Comment: Table.Column _____

Comment: @VDWWD you are completely wrong, the query uses implicit join between the two tables. Explicit joins are better in term of readability, but there is no difference in performance between implicit and explicit joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is quite unclear, however, if I understood correctly, you can't figure out clearly how the database schema you are using is structured and what you'll get from this query.

The query you have written `SELECT`s the data field called `Name` from the table called `Roles`. In order to do this, the query uses data coming from two tables: one is the `Roles` table itself, the other is called `UserRoles`.

It will extract `Name`s data from the `Roles` table only for the `Roles` entries that have the `Id` field matching with the `RoleId` field of the entries in the UserRoles table that have the `UserId` equal to the given `@UserId`.

In other words, this `SELECT` query in will give you as a result a list of `Name`s coming from the entries in the `Roles` table which match the given conditional check, which is what is written after the `where` SQL condition: `where UserRoles.UserId = @userId and UserRoles.RoleId = Roles.Id`.

Finally, the point "." in SQL queries is used to disambiguate between fields (or columns, if you want to call it so) with same name but coming from different tables. It is quite common that all the tables have an Id field, for example. You can identify the correct Id field in your database by writing Table1.Id, Table2.Id, and so on. Even if you don't have naming conflicts in your tables columns, adding the table name can be very good for code readability.

Edit:
As other users correctly pointed out in the comments to your question, you should also have a look to what an SQL `JOIN` operation is. Since you are searching data using information coming from different tables, you are actually doing an implicit `JOIN` on those tables.